# Visual Studio 2019 - cshtml coloר formating

Tags: html

While using the Visual Studio 2019 I am writing my cshtml code, but for some reason the color syntax for html isn't showing.

[This is how it looks in my computer -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU2tf.png)

And this is how it spouse to be -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndxdE.png)

How do I make the html code as in the picture number 2?
Thank you for your help!

** using the visual studio code in dark mode still keeps the html color formatting, is it possible to use dark mode and still have it?
[Visual Studio Code - Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzXab.png)

Comment: Your Visual Studio has "dark mode" turned on. Turn it off and it will look like picture 2. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-personalize-the-ide?view=vs-2019#:~:text=Set%20the%20color%20theme%20for%20the%20IDE,-The%20default%20color&text=On%20the%20menu%20bar%2C%20which,(IDE)%20changes%20to%20Dark.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick respond. but in the visual studio code in dark mode it is showing, is there an option to use dark mode and still have the html color formatting?

Comment: Wait - is the first image from VS Code? You said you were using Visual Studio? They are two completely different products (albeit with confusingly similar names).

Comment: picture 1 & 2 are from the VS 2019 not the code, the last picture is from VS code.